# How to add single Image to all drawables from mainActivity programatically Android

Tags: android

I want to add my image in Drawable s All files according to its size with single image
how it can perform .
Actually I retrieve images from DB Server..While no need to define Server logic in your Answer

Comment: can you tell me what you are going to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add resources in your app at runtime. So you will not be able to add image in your drawables folder.

However you can store in it in a file in your app directory using [Context.openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).